# PolymerJS simple databinding. How to output properties on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'd like to output the value I have saved in my properties.

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBKVwT9lRWWPboNGDibn)

This is a simple `demo-element.html`. And I want to just show the title.

But neither `{{title}}` nor `{{this.title}}` works.

```
<dom-module id="demo-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>

        <h1>'title' in properties not showing</h1>
        <h2>{{this.title}}</h2>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'demo-element',

            properties: {
                title: 'This is a regular Demo Title'
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**How do I output my properties on the screen?**

I am searching for the equivalent of **vue**'s `{{ $data | json }}`

[Plunker Link Again](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBKVwT9lRWWPboNGDibn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is implied when data-binding. So this

```
<h2>{{this.title}}</h2>
```

becomes this

```
<h2>{{title}}</h2>
```

Comment: Could you update my posted Plunker accordingly? Also do you know of a method like vue's {{ $data | json }} for Polymer?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness I'm not familiar with vue but what does `json` return in this context?

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness I just got it now. Updating your plunker.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to assign a `value` property to my `title` property like this:

```
<dom-module id="demo-element">
<template>

    <h1>'title' in properties not showing</h1>
    <h2>{{this.title}}</h2>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'demo-element',

        properties: {
            title: {
                 type: String,
                 value: 'This is a regular Demo Title'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then output the value referencing just the title, without the `this`, like this:

```
<h2>{{ Title }}</h2>
```

Here is the working Plunker:

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/wBKVwT9lRWWPboNGDibn)

**I still wonder if there is an alternative to vue's `{{ $data | json }}` method?**